# Javascript error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I really hope that someone will be able to help me with an error I am getting.  I have an endpoint where I am returning a nested json response.  I am looping through the dataset and writing the values to the console and works great.  When I get to the end it seems to error with this

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'orderTotal')
```

This is my code below and any help would be really appreciated.  I have searched high and low for an answer.

```
 function updateChart() {
        
        async function fetchData() {
            const url = '/admin/Dashboard/GetEvents';
            const response = await fetch(url);

            const datapoints = await response.json();
            console.log(datapoints);

            return datapoints;
        }

        fetchData().then(datapoints => {
        
            var orderTotal=0.0;
            
            for (let i = 0; i < datapoints.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j <= datapoints[i].length; j++) {
                    for (let k = 0; k < datapoints[i].length; k++) {
                        orderTotal+=datapoints[j][k].orderTotal;

                    }


                }
                console.log(orderTotal);
                console.log(j);
                console.log(k);

            }
         

            myChart.update();

        }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    });;


    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM6mA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of the entries of array datapoints is undefined. In this case datapoints[j][k] is undefined and it is leading to the above error. You can verify the log for datapoints to confirm